# Node.js exercise, juggling Async from nodeschool.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, backend

I'm new in node and I'm stuck in an exercise of nodeschool.io, I can't understand why my solution is not valid, I have the sensation that I'm not realizing about something obvious, but I Can't figure out what it is!

My solution:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var results = [];
var count = 0;

function printResults () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    console.log(results[i])
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err)

        results[i] = data.toString();

        count++

        if (count == 3)
            printResults()
        }))

    })
}
```

Correct solution:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var results = [];
var count = 0;

function printResults () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    console.log(results[i])
}

function getDataa(i){
http.get(process.argv[2 + i], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err)

        results[i] = data.toString();

        count++

        if (count == 3)
            printResults()
        }))

    })
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
    getDataa(i);
```

Why when I put the for loop directly doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you have stated what problem your solution is trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I'm still in process of learning how node works, if somebody can explain why this is happening I would appreciate

Comment: Why what is happening?  What is your code trying to do?  What problem are you having?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, As I said I'm starting with node, so I guess in the future  I will be capable to solve it.

Comment: We can help you solve it now - we just need more details on what you are trying to do and what problem you are having.  Can you answer those two questions?

Comment: Here is the description of the exercise: http://www.franticonion.com/node-js-juggling-async-solutions/

Comment: Here the previous exercise: http://www.franticonion.com/node-js-http-collect/

Answer (score 1):

Already solved, I was missing an essential law about async programming:

In this page https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/how-to-write-asynchronous-code.

In the part of "A gotcha with asynchronous code" illustrates the problem I couldn`t understand

Anyway thanks Abe Miessler for your interest.